# Why I am getting error this.variable is null in java class

Tags: java

I am trying to write a small code in java .
I am getting error from method getTotalCost().
can you please check my code and point out what mistake i am doing.

I am creating a class Hamburger .
passing 3 variables to consutuctor.
then its my choice to add tomato or spinach to my Burger.
In my getTotalCost() i am trying to print value if myLettuce.

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.amitsuneja.Lettuce.getCostOfLettuce()" because "this.myLettuce" is null at com.amitsuneja.Hamburger.getTotalCost(Hamburger.java:77) at com.amitsuneja.Main.main(Main.java:8)`

Here is my Hamburger.java

```
public class Hamburger {

private String breadType;
private boolean isMeat;
private double priceOfBurger;
private Lettuce myLettuce;
private boolean addLettuce;
private Tomato myTomato;
private boolean addTomato;
private Carrot myCarrot;
private boolean addCarrot;
private Spinach mySpinach;
private boolean addSpinach;
private double toalCost;

Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);


public Hamburger(String breadType, boolean isMeat, double priceOfBurger) {
    this.breadType = breadType;
    this.isMeat = isMeat;
    this.priceOfBurger = priceOfBurger;
    System.out.println("Current cost of burger is: " + this.priceOfBurger);

    System.out.println(" Would like to add some Lettuce?");
    addLettuce = myScanner.nextBoolean();
    if (addLettuce){
        Lettuce myLettuce1 = new Lettuce(true);
    }else{
        Lettuce myLettuce1 = new Lettuce(false);
        System.out.println("I am in Lettuce: " + myLettuce.getCostOfLettuce() + myLettuce.isHaveLettuce());
    }
    myScanner.nextLine();

    System.out.println(" Would like to add some Tomato?");
    addTomato = myScanner.nextBoolean();
    if (addTomato){
        Tomato myTomato = new Tomato(true);
        }else{
        Tomato myTomato = new Tomato(false);
    }
    myScanner.nextLine();

    System.out.println(" Would like to add some carrot?");
    addCarrot = myScanner.nextBoolean();
    if (addCarrot){
        Carrot myCarrot = new Carrot(true);
    }else{
        Carrot myCarrot = new Carrot(false);
    }
    myScanner.nextLine();

    System.out.println(" Would like to add some Spinach?");
    addSpinach = myScanner.nextBoolean();
    if (addSpinach){
        Spinach mySpinach = new Spinach(true);
    }else{
        Spinach mySpinach = new Spinach(false);
    }
    myScanner.nextLine();
    myScanner.close();

}

public double getPriceOfBurger() {
    return priceOfBurger;
}

public void getTotalCost(){
    System.out.println("I am Here....................price = " + priceOfBurger);
    System.out.println("I am in Lettuce: " + myLettuce.getCostOfLettuce() + myLettuce.isHaveLettuce());


}
```

Here is my Lettuce Class
package com.amitsuneja;

public class Lettuce {

```
private boolean haveLettuce;
private double costOfLettuce;

public Lettuce(boolean haveLettuce) {
    this.haveLettuce = haveLettuce;
    this.costOfLettuce =2d;
}


public boolean isHaveLettuce() {
    return haveLettuce;
}

public void setHaveLettuce(boolean haveLettuce) {
    this.haveLettuce = haveLettuce;
}

public double getCostOfLettuce() {
    return costOfLettuce;
}

public void setCostOfLettuce(double costOfLettuce) {
    this.costOfLettuce = costOfLettuce;
}
```

}

Comment: Cannot invoke "com.amitsuneja.Lettuce.getCostOfLettuce()" because "this.myLettuce" is null at com.amitsuneja.Hamburger.getTotalCost -- I think that's quite explicit. Try reading it carefully, and using the debugger if that doesn't make it clear.

Comment: Amit in your hamburger constructor you are create a local variable myLettuce1 but then calling a method of the member variable myLettuce.  You need to instantiate myLettuce before using it.  Maybe you don't need to create myLettuce1 varible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this code

```
 if (addLettuce){
        Lettuce myLettuce1 = new Lettuce(true);
    }else{
        Lettuce myLettuce1 = new Lettuce(false);
        System.out.println("I am in Lettuce: " + myLettuce.getCostOfLettuce() + myLettuce.isHaveLettuce());
    }
```

to -

```
if (addLettuce){
            myLettuce = new Lettuce(true);
}else{
            myLettuce = new Lettuce(false);
            System.out.println("I am in Lettuce: " + myLettuce.getCostOfLettuce() + myLettuce.isHaveLettuce());
        }
```

Comment: The issue here is that instead of updating the global reference variable myLettuce you have created new reference variable and assigned the object to those. And your myLettuce ref is null. Hence you are getting NullPointerException when trying to access the method of a null object.

Comment: Also, you can further improvise your code using Decorator pattern here instead of using so many conditionals

Comment: i am learner , have not read  Decorator  till now